# d3js svg not visible in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, svg

I am using two svgs in my code. One is using HTML, another is using d3:

```
    <svg>
        <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="24" style="stroke:#006600; fill:#00cc00"/>
    </svg>

 var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("xhtml:div")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",500)
            .attr("height",50)
            .attr("fill","yellow")
            .attr("stroke","orange")
            ;
```

The first one is showing, second one is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that your actual code?  `d3` is JavaScript, you need script tags if you are embedding it in HTML.  Also, the `SVG` element does not have a fill or stroke attribute.  You should style it like any conventional **html element** using CSS.

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<svg>
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="24" style="stroke:#006600; fill:#00cc00" />
</svg>

<script>
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("xhtml:div")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .style("background-color", "yellow")
    .style("border", "2px solid orange");
</script>
```

Comment: I did the same. Means I added svg in script tag.

Comment: Your code works fine but why ` .attr("fill","yellow")
            .attr("stroke","orange")
` didn't work?

Comment: @learner, the `svg` element is an HTML element.  HTML elements do not have those attributes.  Things inside an `svg` tag are svg elements, most have those attributes.